# Where to store server side cookie in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, node-redis

My backend/server is calling a remote REST service `apples` which requires authentication. The flow is as following:

1. Call `http://remote.service.com/api/login` with use of ExpressJS $http module. This service returns valid cookie, given successful authentication
2. Call `http://remote.service.com/api/apples` with use of ExpressJS $http module. and send cookie retrieved from step 1

Since the server is calling `apple` service many times in row, I want to avoid authenticating each time  and would like some tip on how to store the cookie from step 1 so I can reuse it next time. Should I use `node-redis` or maybe `ExpressJS cookie-parser`? How should I handle cookie expiration?

**Edit:**
Cookie can be saved in a global variable. See comments below.

Comment: is this being done in response to a client action? or is this more of a maintenance script. If it's just a maintenance script you could just store the cookie in a variable, and then on subsequent iterations, if said variable is defined, don't request a new cookie.

Comment: The remote service call can be triggered either by user or be run on scheduled time interval. Meaning the cookie should not be stored at users session

Comment: And, is there a reason you can't just request a cookie on first call and store it in a variable, and reuse it until it expires?

Comment: Do you use different credentials per user, or is it the same credentials app-wide

Comment: Same credentials for all users. Authentication is only done between the server and remote host, not for each user. I guess your suggestion with a global variable might work well for this purpose. Is it sufficient to declare new variable at the top of my JavaScript file or do I need to export it as well?

Comment: top should be fine, unless you wanted to be able to run multiple instances of the app, in which case you could store it externally (such as in some form of a db) that all instances can access. (Though it probably wouldn't be too bad for each instance to use it's own set of credentials anyway)

Comment: Thanks! I´ll try that. Since I don´t know if the cookie stored in variable is expired I just need to try calling apple service with retrieved cookie, and if it fails with status code 401 i need to re-authenticate?

Comment: Yup, that's what i would suggest. Hopefully a 401 request is relatively quick. Doing it that way will handle both expired cookies, and any chance of a cookie being... destroyed early.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a session store for saving session token. Though MongoDB itself can do that, Redis is one of the best option. If you don't use session store, scaling up in a cluster model will end up in trouble, as the different app server instances won't be able to identify a user authorized by another server.